# KSQLDB Push query doesn't emit all changes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I'm new to ksqlDB and I started experimenting with very basic aggregation. I have created topic where I get few messages every second, those get streamed and then output to a materialised table.

I can see my stream is up to date with the topic, but the materialised table doesn't output each change. I couldn't find anywhere in the docs how to emit every update not just one every 1 or 2 seconds.

This is my setup:

Topic (JSON):

```
key: username, value: { balance_change }
```

Stream:

```
create stream balance_stream (user varchar key, balance_change bigint) 
  with (kafka_topic='balance', value_format='JSON');
```

Materialised Table:

```
create table balance_table as 
select user, 
       sum(balance_change) balance 
from balance_stream 
group by user 
emit changes;
```

And as you can see in the video below, it's very slow to get total balance for my user bob:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HmCA3ueUo0

How can I get all the updates from my `balance_table`?

---

There are less than 900 messages in the table, which should instantly  sum all the values.

```
Name                 : BALANCE_TABLE
Type                 : TABLE
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Key format           : KAFKA
Value format         : JSON
Kafka topic          : BALANCE_TABLE (partitions: 1, replication: 1)
Statement            : CREATE TABLE BALANCE_TABLE WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='BALANCE_TABLE', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1) AS SELECT
  BALANCE_STREAM.USER USER,
  SUM(BALANCE_STREAM.BALANCE_CHANGE) BALANCE
FROM BALANCE_STREAM BALANCE_STREAM
GROUP BY BALANCE_STREAM.USER
EMIT CHANGES;

 Field   | Type                           
------------------------------------------
 USER    | VARCHAR(STRING)  (primary key) 
 BALANCE | BIGINT                         
------------------------------------------

Queries that write from this TABLE
-----------------------------------
CTAS_BALANCE_TABLE_155 (RUNNING) : CREATE TABLE BALANCE_TABLE WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='BALANCE_TABLE', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1) AS SELECT   BALANCE_STREAM.USER USER,   SUM(BALANCE_STREAM.BALANCE_CHANGE) BALANCE FROM BALANCE_STREAM BALANCE_STREAM GROUP BY BALANCE_STREAM.USER EMIT CHANGES;

For query topology and execution plan please run: EXPLAIN <QueryId>

Local runtime statistics
------------------------
messages-per-sec:      0.28   total-messages:       814     last-message: 2021-06-17T16:08:43.091Z

(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic BALANCE_TABLE)

Consumer Groups summary:

Consumer Group       : _confluent-ksql-ksqldbquery_CTAS_BALANCE_TABLE_155

Kafka topic          : balance
Max lag              : 0

 Partition | Start Offset | End Offset | Offset | Lag 
------------------------------------------------------
 0         | 0            | 21230      | 21230  | 0   
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was with the default server settings

this can be fixed by adjusting value for `'commit.interval.ms'`

Comment: What value did you set?